# where did the term $\omega$-limit set originate from?

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems, math-history, chaos-theory

What it says on the tin. I've always used the phrase 'in the limit of all things' but hearing '$\omega$-limit' in a chaos theory class has me wanting to use the term. That said, I'd feel really awkward using it pseudo-artistically without knowing its history.

Could someone please enlighten me regarding how this term came into being (i.e. what field of mathematics, approximately how long ago, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ultimately the mathematical usage can be traced back to the *Apocalypse of St. John*, also known as the *Book of Revelations* in the *New Testament*, and,other classical/ancient sources.  (If I am not mistaken, the phrase "Alpha and Omega" was used, outside of the *Apocalypse*, in the ancient world to denote the beginnings and endings of all things; the religious writers adopted it from a broader context.)  Of course those usages were taken in turn from the observation that $\alpha$ and $\omega$ are the first and last letters of the Greek alphabet.  The usage of $\omega$ to denote the ultimate end point of any given situation has thus been around since antiquity, I believe; it crept into the common tongue and was imported into mathematical terminology from there.  My take on it, in any event.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always, ***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: While I would've preferred to also know the context in which it crept into nonlinear dynamical systems, this works well enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: @ Atash:  you know, I thought after I posted that it would be good to know/write on that, but truthfully, I'm not sure.  The earliest source I know for the use of $\omega$ mathematically, in the sense of "final limit" etc., is the papers of Smale from the 1960's.  But I'm pretty sure he didn't invent the usage.  Maybe if one checked the references in his papers, one could begin a serious search?  Anyway, thanks for the "thanks" and of course, the "acceptance"!  Glad to contrubute.

Comment: This is an excellent answer.

Comment: @copper.hat:  why, thanks; glad you liked it; always appreciate kind words from such a "heavy" as yourself!  Haven't been to the Med much lately, myself; the scene there ain't what it used to be!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha$ is the first letter of the Greek alphabet and $\omega$ is the last.